# How to dynamically add new tab onclick and populate pre-designed fragment to that?

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs

I am creating an application which requires tabs. I created a Fragment with a design in it. How could i dynamically add tabs like adding tabs in chrome and removing exactly like chrome tabs and populate the newly added tab with the fragment i designed.

My Activity code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        POSFragment hello = new POSFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, hello, "HELLO");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

FRAGMENT CODE:

```
public class POSFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Inflating the layout for this fragment **/
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.posfragment, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Main activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eazypos.app.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="416dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:text="Hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any forum or link i can research on.. or any quick code snippet I can work on. I am very new to this..

Comment: viewpager, tabhost

Comment: @Loki. I am new to this. Any reference link having this tutorials?

Comment: try this maybe https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-material-design-tabbed-interface-in-an-android-app--cms-30120

Answer (score 0):

To learn how to make tabs and working with them you can learn it from [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) .

To dynamically add tabs as per your requirement you can do something like this:

My code is based on the example described in the link above:

In MainActivity do this:

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
if(your logic here){
 adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");}
else if(logic){
 adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
}
       viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How could this add tabs ? This may add fragments right? But what i need is to add fargments at the same time multiple tabs must be added as in like chrome

Comment: @KarthikCP check now.

Comment: I get error here `private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new POSFragment(), "ONE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }`

`Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.eazypos.app.POSFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'`

Comment: Change your POSFragment from fragment to android.support.v4.app.Fragment (see import statement) and accept the answer too..